# Loading a ListView from a WebService

Tags: android, web-services, http, tomcat, servlets

Hello I'm trying to load my listview with data from a database via a webservice. I have tried to do this in two fold and I am not very confident in each stage.

1. return a list/array from my tomcat here is the code

   ```
   String mylist[] = {"", "", "", "", "", ""};

   try {
       Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);

       String query1 = "select username from Users where online = 'yes'";
       PreparedStatement preparedStmt1 = con.prepareStatement(query1);
       ResultSet result1 = preparedStmt1.executeQuery();

       int i = 0;
       while (result1.next()) {
           mylist[i] = result1.getString(1);               
       }
   } catch (Exception e1) {
       e1.printStackTrace();
   }

   out.println(mylist);
   out.close();
   ```

My question here would be is this the right way to return a list from a webservice?

1. The second stage is to get the list to my list view, here is my code

   ```
   try {
       HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
       URI webservice = new URI("http://192.168.0.3:8080/Users/users");
       request.setURI(webservice);
       HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

       BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                       .getContent()));

       while ((rd.readLine()) != null) {

           ArrayList<String> list = rd.readLine();
       }
   } catch (Exception e1) {
       e1.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

This seems to only work when the webservice returns single lines of text. How do I retrieve something like an array from a Http request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A WebService can only return xml or string type, so you can put your list into a string with format like this:

```
"this is a string 1; this is a string 2; this is a string 3"
```

The **server side** look like:

```
  StringBuilder myList = new StringBuilder();

 try {
     Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
     con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);

     String query1 = "select username from Users where online = 'yes'";
     PreparedStatement preparedStmt1 = con.prepareStatement(query1);
     ResultSet result1 = preparedStmt1.executeQuery();

     int i = 0;
      while (result1.next()) {
          myList.append( result1.getString(1) + ";");               
  }
} catch (Exception e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
 }

out.println(mylist.toString());
out.close();
```

Then from **Android client side**, you can get it by String.split(";"); 
Here is an example:

```
private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is)
{
String line = "";
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
// Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 1024 * 4);
// Read response until the end
try
{

    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
    {
        total.append(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "error build string" + e.getMessage());
}
// Return full string
return total.toString();
 }

InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
String strResponse = inputStreamToString(is);
String mylist[] = strResponse .split(";");
```

Or you can use JSON to parse an list object and transfer from WebService to Android client

Comment: The problem with merging all the strings is you need to know how many strings the sql statement will return and that will change from time to time

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand exactly what you want. You can read data from database line by line, then you put all lines into a string with format above and send to client.You can use StringBuilder instead of string array to build the formatted string above.I also updated my answer.

Comment: My point was that the number of strings I get from the database to perform this action "this is a string 1; this is a string 2; this is a string 3" will change dynamically and this method above requires that you know the number of strings. 

My app will have several users and this is supposed to show you the list of all users logged on at a particular time.

Comment: @Amanni: Do you check my updated answer? You don't need to know number of strings (actually my code doesn't need it). Whenever you check the online users (by query database and read to end), you will send this list to client, don't you?  So, instead use array string to send, you can parse this into one formatted string with StringBuilder. So, what is the problem? Have you tried this?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it, I'll give it a try now